# Setting an Android Tint Color Pre Lollipop

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have written an Android custom renderer for a checkbox control.

I set the checkbox disabled color like so

```
Control.ButtonTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(element.DisabledColor.ToAndroid());
```

where Control is an Android.Widget.CheckBox

This does not work prior to Lollipop and I get an error

> CheckboxRenderer.SetDisabledColor (Incident.UserControls.Checkbox
>   element) Java.Lang.LinkageError: no method with
>   name='setButtonTintList'
>   signature='(Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;)V' in class
>   Landroid/widget/CompoundButton; no method with
>   name='setButtonTintList'
>   signature='(Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;)V' in class
>   Landroid/widget/CompoundButton;

I have found some mention of using DrawableCompat to do this but can't figure out how to do it in Xamarin/C#

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompactCheckbox instead of Your base Android.Widget.Checkbox might do the trick.

Also to change colour at runtime you could use this:

```
ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList(_YourView , ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.ParseColor(Resources.GetString(Resource.Color.blueLine))));
```

Actually, the problem with things not working pre-lollipop is that Android KitKat is obsolete and so are the rest of the versions below so to have features that are new to Android you need to use the Appcompact library for backward compatibility.

Anyways, Goodluck! Happy coding

Comment: Do mark it as the right answer if it works thank you @SteveChadbourne

Comment: Will do. Works well on Nougat now need to test on Kit-Kat

Comment: Sure Goodluck sir